# how using asynctask for add to arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, android-asynctask, while-loop

how using 'do while' in asynctask for add to array list?Please explain mobile code,Thanks to all those who respond

code :

```
public List<msgstore> results =new ArrayList<msgstore>();


    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>task=new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
                            ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
                            @Override
                            protected void onPreExecute() {
                                pd.setTitle("Process");
                                pd.setMessage("Processing ....");
                                pd.setCancelable(false);
                                pd.setIndeterminate(true);
                                pd.show();
                            }


                            @Override
                            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                                do{

                                      String d=mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex("address"));
                                      String p= mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex("phone")); 
                                      int    k=mCur.getInt(mCur.getColumnIndex("key"));
                                      int    i=mCur.getInt(mCur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                                      long t=mCur.getLong(mCur.getColumnIndex("registertime"));
                                      results.add(new msgstore(d,p,k,i,t));


                                  }while(mCur.moveToNext());                
                                return null;
                            }


                            @Override
                            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                                pd.dismiss();
                            }
                        };
                        task.execute((Void[])null);
```

Comment: Can you explain what problem you are having?

Comment: @codeMagic, No working ,the crash app

Comment: If the app is crashing then you need to provide the stacktrace from the crash so we can help

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'll add my comment here. Where is mCur defined? You do a do/while loop using moveToNext which is very dangerous because the cursor may be empty.

Try doing a while loop instead

```
while(mCur.moveToNext()) {
     String d=mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex("address"));
     String p= mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex("phone")); 
     int    k=mCur.getInt(mCur.getColumnIndex("key"));
     int    i=mCur.getInt(mCur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
     long t=mCur.getLong(mCur.getColumnIndex("registertime"));
     results.add(new msgstore(d,p,k,i,t));
}
```

Also be sure to close the cursor afterwards